# Read content from non xp:inputText field with ssjs

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

Is there a way to read a field with ssjs that is created via client side javascript (so is no xp:input field, it's a simple html input field wich is in the notes form-tag)?
I know i can send the value with an XAgent, but i hope there is another beautiful way. Somthing like `context.getSubmittedValue("fieldName")`

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the values in SSJS with

```
paramValues.get("fieldName").toString();
```

In Java you can access the parameters from the request parameter values map:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
Map<String, String[]> pMap = ec.getRequestParameterValuesMap();
```